# Have a buy button show up after 3 minutes, but instantly after second or greater page view (Javascript preferred)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've already created a script that shows the buy button after 3 minutes, but I'd also like to add a feature on top of it that shows the button instantly if the person has already viewed the page before. I wasn't sure how to go about that part. Here's that I've got for the current timed buy button:

```
<script>
function timedBuyButton() {
document.getElementById("buyButton").innerHTML = "Buy Button";
}
</script>
```

I then make an empty div container with id "buyButton" where I buy button to show up. And lastly, I put the trigger in the body tag:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(timedBuyButton, 180000)">
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Use local storage or a cookie to remember the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
  // your function, put at the top for clarity because it would be hoisted.
  function timedBuyButton() {
    document.getElementById("buyButton").innerHTML = "Buy Button";
  }

  // the magic happens here.
  localStorage.visitNumber = localStorage.visitNumber === undefined ? 0 : (Number(localStorage.visitNumber) + 1);
</script>

<!-- and here. -->
<body onload="setTimeout(timedBuyButton, Number(localStorage.visitNumber) < 1 ? 180000 : 0)">
```

This sets a value to localStorage (note that you can only set strings to localstorage, so numbers get transformed into stringified versions of themselves). This value persists across refreshes.

If you load the page for the first time, localStorage.visitNumber will be equal to undefined; Therefore, that ternary will set it to "0".

Thereafter, when you load the page, localStorage.visitNumber will not be undefined, and so the ternary will increment it.

The ternary in the onload statement will just fire a timer with a timeout of 0 if it sees a visitNumber of 1 or greater as the value there, otherwise it will count out your full 3 minutes.